# How do I get link and text when the <a> wraps another element using XPath?

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath

The example below reflects data similar to what I'm using (I can't show my live data, due to company policy). It is pulled from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491746/in-java-how-do-i-parse-a-string-bigger-than-int-size/9491778#9491778) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484402/render-a-map-from-openstreetmap-data-with-an-open-source-3d-engine/9491727#9491727) answer.

My goal is to pull the text of the `<a>` element, as well as the link itself.

```
from lxml import html

post1 = """<p><code>Integer.parseInt</code> <em>couldn't</em> do the job, unless you were happy to lose data. Think about what you're asking for here.</p>&#xA;&#xA;<p>Try <a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29"><code>Long.parseLong(String)</code></a> or <a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String%29"><code>new BigInteger(String)</code></a> for really big integers.</p>&#xA;
"""

post2 = """
<p><code>Integer.parseInt</code> <em>couldn't</em> do the job, unless you were happy to lose data. Think about what you're asking for here.</p>&#xA;&#xA;<p>Try <a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29"><code>Long.parseLong(String)</code></a> or <a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String%29"><code>new BigInteger(String)</code></a> for really big integers.</p>&#xA;
"""
doc = html.fromstring(post1)
for link in doc.xpath('//a'):
    print link.text, link.get('href')
```

Unfortunately, this returns the following:

```
None http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29
None http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String%29
```

Notice that my `link.text` is empty. This is because the link wraps a `<code>` block.

If I use `post2`, it returns the correct results:

```
PROJ.4 http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/
OpenSceneGraph http://www.openscenegraph.org/
```

How can I modify my loop to handle both the standard URL (`post2`) and a link wrapping another object (`post1`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
print link.text, link.get('href')
```

to

```
print link.text_content(), link.get('href')
```

then your output will be

```
Long.parseLong(String) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29
new BigInteger(String) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String%29
```

for both `post1` and `post2` as requested.